# Insert a Class or ID to HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to insert a class or id to an HTML element for styling but not able to figure it out. Below is my code:

```
$('<li/>').append($('<p>', {html: val.title}), $('<p>', {html: 'Posted on ' + split[0]})
```

I have tried this but no luck:

```
$('<p class="vtitle">', {html: val.title})
```

Comment: Thanks guys, i didn't realize it was that easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass `id` as you are passing `html`

```
$('<li/>').append($('<p>', {html: val.title, id : "myId"}))
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8bqeb/)

Complete Code

```
$('<li/>').append($('<p>', {html: val.title, id : 'id1'}), 
                  $('<p>', {html: 'Posted on ' + split[0], id : 'id2'})
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this (assumed `val` object and `split` array available within current scope)

```
var p1 = $('<p/>', { 'html': val.title, 'class':'vtitle' }),
    p2 =  $('<p/>', { 'html':'Posted on ' + split[0], 'class':'para' });
$('<li/>').append(p1, p2);
```

[**An Example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/XTGT6/)

Answer (score 1):

Just add the id or class when creating the elements :

```
var p1 = $('<p />', {id: 'paragraph_1', html: val.title}), 
    p2 = $('<p />', {'class': 'paragraph_2', html: 'Posted on ' + split[0]});

$('<li />').append(p1, p2)
```

note that class is a reserved keyword in javascript and should be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

To Add an attribute **Use [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

```
$("p").attr("id","#yourId");
```